# Using jackson 2.5.4 jar to de-serializing polymorphic types containing in property of property

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to de-serialize following json:

```
{
    "partnerName" : "PartnerName",
    "mpnId" : "1234567",
    "profileType" : "partner_network_profile",
    "links" : {
        "self" : {
            "uri" : "/v1/profiles/PartnerNetworkProfile?mpnId=1234567",
            "method" : "GET",
            "headers" : []
        }
    },
    "attributes" : {
        "objectType" : "PartnerNetworkProfile"
    }
}
```

the type information is included in inner property object i.e. `attributes.objectType`

Class mapping that I tried is this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "attributes.objectType", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChildClass.class, name = "PartnerNetworkProfile")
})
BaseClass{
    @JsonProperty("links")
    private Map<String, Link> links;

    @JsonProperty("attributes")
    private Attributes attributes;

//getter & setters
}

ChildClass extends BaseClass {
   @JsonProperty("partnerName")
    private String partnerName;

    @JsonProperty("mpnId")
    private String mpnId;

    @JsonProperty("profileType")
    private String profileType;

    //Getter & setters
}

public class Attributes {

    private String objectType;
}
```

But `property = "attributes.objectType"` does not work.
I am not finding a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json parsing :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
String json = "{\"partnerName\":\"PartnerName\",\"mpnId\":\"1234567\",\"profileType\":\"partner_network_profile\",\"links\":{\"self\":{\"uri\":\"/v1/profiles/PartnerNetworkProfile?mpnId=1234567\",\"method\":\"GET\",\"headers\":[]}},\"attributes\":{\"objectType\":\"PartnerNetworkProfile\"}}";
ObjectNode rootNode = (ObjectNode)mapper.readTree(json);
JsonNode typeNode = rootNode.path("attributes");
if (JsonNodeType.OBJECT == typeNode.getNodeType()) {
    System.out.println("Result:" + typeNode.get("objectType").asText());
}
```

Custom classes :

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "attributes.objectType")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChildClass.class, name = "PartnerNetworkProfile")
})
class BaseClass {
    @JsonProperty("links")
    private Map<String, Link> links;
    @JsonProperty("attributes")
    private Attributes attributes;

    public Map<String, Link> getLinks() {
        return links;
    }

    public void setLinks(Map<String, Link> links) {
        this.links = links;
    }

    public Attributes getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(Attributes attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    @JsonProperty("partnerName")
    private String partnerName;
    @JsonProperty("mpnId")
    private String mpnId;
    @JsonProperty("profileType")
    private String profileType;

    public String getPartnerName() {
        return partnerName;
    }

    public void setPartnerName(String partnerName) {
        this.partnerName = partnerName;
    }

    public String getMpnId() {
        return mpnId;
    }

    public void setMpnId(String mpnId) {
        this.mpnId = mpnId;
    }

    public String getProfileType() {
        return profileType;
    }

    public void setProfileType(String profileType) {
        this.profileType = profileType;
    }
}

class Link {
    private String uri;
    private String method;
    private String[] headers;

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }

    public void setMethod(String method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public String[] getHeaders() {
        return headers;
    }

    public void setHeaders(String[] headers) {
        this.headers = headers;
    }
}
class Attributes {
    @JsonProperty("objectType")
    private String objectType;

    public String getObjectType() {
        return objectType;
    }

    public void setObjectType(String objectType) {
        this.objectType = objectType;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a java class to which I wan it to be mapped. I that case, your solution is not going to help.

Comment: There can be more than one child class like ChildClass1 with attributes.objectType = 'ChildClass1', ChildClass2 with attributes.objectType = 'ChildClass2' and objects of different child class can be in a single JSON array which I want to de-serialize to List<BaseClass> object on which I will itrate over and check instance of to get specific ChildClass object. So, we have to use JsonSubTypes.

Comment: The problem is that 'property = "attributes.objectType"' is not working. I have also mentioned this in my question.

Comment: I tried with the parsing code given in my answer and it is giving proper output.